# Connect to Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to connect to Google App Engine's Datastore from my local machine in Java. I will not be using the service with an application on GAE, it will be on AWS.

**What I tried**

I tried using
`DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();`, but I think it is for when the application is hosted on GAE.

Right now, I have Google Storage up and running using a json credentials file fetched with the System Variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**. The connection works fine, so my guess is that I might have to do something similar to Storage. 
I did something like this for Storage :

```
HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);

        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
            Collection<String> bigqueryScopes = StorageScopes.all();
            credential = credential.createScoped(bigqueryScopes);
        }

        Storage client = new Storage.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("APPLICATION_NAME")
                .build();
```

**The question**

So my question is : How can I connect to Google App Engine Datastore from outside of Google App Engine?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you move to the [gcloud-java client library](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/). It is built on top of the code that you are currently using, and makes it easier to work with the Datastore and Storage, although the documentation is virtually non-existent (as of April 2016).

This is how you connect to the Datastore using this library:

```
AuthCredentials credentials = AuthCredentials.createFor(account, key);
DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.builder()
        .authCredentials(credentials)
        .projectId(projectId)
        .namespace(NAMESPACE)
        .build();
Datastore datastore = options.service();
```

Same for the Storage, but with StorageOptions.

TIP: Open gcloud-java project in GitHub - the link is on the page that I referenced earlier. There is a folder which contains examples of how to use Datastore and Storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! The project manages to "work", but now I get a different error telling me that the api is not enabled for my project : The Cloud Datastore API is not enabled for the project PROJECT_NAME
What is wierd is that I have enabled it in the api console : [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?)

Do you know if I have to do something else?

Thank you!

Comment: another option on  dev is to use the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing to a service account json generated from the credential tab in the cloud console such as `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json`

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much for your help, I had API beta2 instead of beta3. Activating beta3 worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

With Andrei Volgin's awesome help, I managed to be able to connect to Datastore from an application outside of Google App Engine. Here is what I did as of April 2016 :

- Enable Datastore API v1beta3. The default in App Engine for me was v1beta2. https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/datastore.googleapis.com/overview?project=PROJECT_NAME
- Get a credentials file for the service with Datastore activated.
- You can set the credentials file in a system variable with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json`
- I wrote this code as a test and the connection worked

  ```
  DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.builder()
          .projectId("PROJECT_NAME")
          .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(
                  new FileInputStream("/PATH/TO/CREDENTIALS.json"))).build();
  Datastore datastore = options.service();
  Query<Entity> query =
          Query.gqlQueryBuilder(Query.ResultType.ENTITY, "SELECT * FROM user").build();
  QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
  while (results.hasNext()) {
      Entity result = results.next();
      System.out.println(result.getString("id"));
  }
  ```